# Oracle Find and Rewrite Consecutive Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that includes rows like ;

```
ID  DATE
1   1.01.2018 13:30
1   1.01.2018 13:31
2   1.01.2018 13:32
2   1.01.2018 13:33
1   1.01.2018 13:34
3   1.01.2018 13:35
3   1.01.2018 13:35
3   1.01.2018 13:35
3   1.01.2018 13:36
1   1.01.2018 13:37
3   1.01.2018 13:38
4   1.01.2018 13:39
4   1.01.2018 13:40
1   1.01.2018 13:40
```

I want to find start and end dates of events.

Desired Output;

```
ID    START_DATE              END_DATE
1   1.01.2018 13:30     1.01.2018 13:31
2   1.01.2018 13:32     1.01.2018 13:33
1   1.01.2018 13:34     1.01.2018 13:34
3   1.01.2018 13:35     1.01.2018 13:36
1   1.01.2018 13:37     1.01.2018 13:37
3   1.01.2018 13:38     1.01.2018 13:38
4   1.01.2018 13:39     1.01.2018 13:40
1   1.01.2018 13:40     1.01.2018 13:40
```

in ordered date If same id continues

- start date = it is first date
- end date = it is last date until id changes

How can I write this query?

Thank you.

Comment: . . You have ties in the data.  This makes it almost impossible to guarantee a solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  For this version, I recommend the difference of row numbers:

```
select id, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum_i
      from t
     ) t
group by id, (seqnum - seqnum_i);
```

As stated, this problem is indeterminate, because there are ties in the date time values.  The following comes close:

```
select id, min(dte), max(dte)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by dte) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by dte) as seqnum_i
      from (select distinct id, dte from t) t
     ) t
group by id, (seqnum - seqnum_i)
```

(see db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd6b86e851831c19f149e488689870d4))  The db<>fiddle has two rows for "4" because of this issue.

But the ties make the problem indeterminate.

EDIT:

Ouch.  Those duplicates make this a hard problem.  It is solvable using window functions.  The key idea is to compare the previous date for the id to the previous date in the data.  That defines the groups.

So:

```
select id, min(dte), max(dte)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_id_dte = prev_dte then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by dte) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(dte) over (partition by id order by dte) as prev_id_dte,
                   (select max(dte) from t t2 where t2.dte < t.dte) as prev_dte
            from (select distinct id, dte
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=577d759e980d5a67918e92a22725c69c) is the db<>fiddle for this version.

I'm not thrilled with the subquery.  But I don't think there is an easy way to get the previous value from grouped data using window functions.  There is a method, but it requires several levels of nesting.  The subquery is simpler.

Comment: Very neat solution.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It returns 4 separate rows for id = 3, not 2 consolidated rows as expected.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . How do you get that?  I don't think you understand how this works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Use the SQL data from my response and try it out. Your query returns 10 rows in Oracle 12.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I've amended the answer to provide an explanation.  Your solution is no better (well, more complicated, but not improved results).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, agreed, with this change it's good (at least as good as it can be).

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . You'll be interested in my most recent edit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's work pretty well. Moreover, considering the data structure is less than great.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the rows in not clear since there are multiple rows for a date/time value. Therefore, I decided to order by date/date + id.

**Note**: I changed the column name from `date` to `d` since `DATE` is a reserved word in Oracle.

If your data is:

```
create table t (
  id number(6),
  d date
);

insert into t (id, d) values (1, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:30:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (1, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:31:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (2, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:32:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (2, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:33:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (1, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:34:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (3, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:35:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (3, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:35:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (3, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:35:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (3, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:36:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (1, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:37:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (3, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:38:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (4, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:39:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (4, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:40:00');
insert into t (id, d) values (1, timestamp '2018-01-01 13:40:00');
```

A solution for your query could be:

```
with x as (
select
    t.*,
    case when id = lag(id) over(order by d, id) then 0 else 1 end as ini,
    case when id = lead(id) over(order by d, id) then 0 else 1 end as fin
  from t  
),
y as (
select * from x where ini <> 0 or fin <> 0
)
select
    id,
    d as start_date,
    case when fin = 1 then d else lead(d) over (order by d, id) end as end_date
  from y where ini = 1
```

Result:

```
ID  START_DATE             END_DATE
--  ---------------------  ---------------------
1   2018-01-01 13:30:00.0  2018-01-01 13:32:00.0
2   2018-01-01 13:32:00.0  2018-01-01 13:34:00.0
1   2018-01-01 13:34:00.0  2018-01-01 13:34:00.0
3   2018-01-01 13:35:00.0  2018-01-01 13:37:00.0
1   2018-01-01 13:37:00.0  2018-01-01 13:37:00.0
3   2018-01-01 13:38:00.0  2018-01-01 13:38:00.0
4   2018-01-01 13:39:00.0  2018-01-01 13:39:00.0
1   2018-01-01 13:40:00.0  2018-01-01 13:40:00.0
4   2018-01-01 13:40:00.0  2018-01-01 13:40:00.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished with pattern-matching.

```
SELECT THE_ID,
       TO_CHAR(MIN_DATE , 'MM.DD.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS START_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(MAX_DATE , 'MM.DD.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS END_DATE
FROM T
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
         ORDER BY "DATE"
         MEASURES
           ID AS THE_ID,
           MIN("DATE") AS MIN_DATE,
           MAX("DATE") AS MAX_DATE
         ONE ROW PER MATCH
         AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
         PATTERN (IN_RUN{0,} END_RUN )
         DEFINE
           IN_RUN AS (ID = NEXT(ID)),
           END_RUN AS ID != ANY (NEXT(ID) , PREV(ID)))
ORDER BY START_DATE ASC, END_DATE ASC;
```

Result:

```
    THE_ID START_DATE          END_DATE
---------- ------------------- -------------------
     1 01.01.2018 13:30:00 01.01.2018 13:31:00
     2 01.01.2018 13:32:00 01.01.2018 13:33:00
     1 01.01.2018 13:34:00 01.01.2018 13:34:00
     3 01.01.2018 13:35:00 01.01.2018 13:36:00
     1 01.01.2018 13:37:00 01.01.2018 13:37:00
     3 01.01.2018 13:38:00 01.01.2018 13:38:00
     4 01.01.2018 13:39:00 01.01.2018 13:40:00
     1 01.01.2018 13:40:00 01.01.2018 13:40:00

8 rows selected.
```

Comment: FYI: Pattern matching is a new feature in Oracle 12c.

Comment: That's not how I'd write this particular query, but I love `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, so +1.  :)  I'd be really interested to see the relative performance of the solutions on this page vs. a large data set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to build the answer step-by-step.

Step 1 - Order the rows by the timestamp and use `LEAD` to figure out when each "group" ends.  That is, when the value of `id` changes in the next row.  Mark any row as a "Y" where this is true.

Step 2 - Count the marked "Y" values prior to the current row. This count will be the "group number".  This gives each consecutive groups of  the same ID the same "group number".

Step 3 - Now, take the `min` and `max` timestamp in each "group number" as the start and end time of that event.

It may not be as compact and cool as other possible solutions, but I have a much better chance of remembering how it worked when I come back to it in 6 months.  That's just me.

Here it is all together.

```
WITH input (id, ts) AS (
SELECT 1, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:30','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:31','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:32','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:33','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:34','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:35','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:35','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:35','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:36','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:37','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:38','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:39','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:40','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE(  '01.01.2018 13:40','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL ), 
-- Solution starts here
input_with_group_markers as (
SELECT id, ts,
case when lead(id,1) over ( order by ts ) != id THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END last_row_in_group
FROM input
),
grouped_input as (
SELECT igwm.*, count(last_row_in_group) OVER ( order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ) group_number
FROM input_with_group_markers igwm )
SELECT min(id) id, 
       to_char(min(ts),'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') event_start, 
       to_char(max(ts),'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') event_end
FROM grouped_input
group by group_number
order by group_number;
```

Comment: Thanks for your  solution and care.